# 独自アノテーションでエラーメッセージを出し分けたい

Tags: java

現在Javaのbean validationで独自アノテーションによるバリーデーションを作っています。

https://qiita.com/shotana/items/42949b88c6c670b1ed22

上のリンク先を参考にしているのですが、
メッセージを複数出すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

htmlバリデーションの開始タグと閉じタグがあるかどうかのチェックをしたくて、その際の「開始タグがありません」と「終了タグがありません」を出し分けたいです。

messageにエラーメッセージは入れるのですが、defaultだけでなく複数を出し分けるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
メッセージのセット方法が知りたいです。

わかる方よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConstraintValidatorContext`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_the_code_constraintvalidatorcontext_code) を利用することで実現できます。

検証処理は適当ですが、次のような感じの実装になります:

```java
public class TagOpenCloseValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TagOpenClose, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // デフォルトのメッセージを抑制する
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        return isValidOpen(value, context) & isValidClose(value, context);
    }

    // 開始タグの検証
    private boolean isValidOpen(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final boolean ret = value.contains("<mytag>");
        if (!ret) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("開始タグがありません").addConstraintViolation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // 終了タグの検証
    private boolean isValidClose(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final boolean ret = value.contains("</mytag>");
        if (!ret) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{com.github.yukihane.so.validation.TagOpenClose.noclose}")
                .addConstraintViolation();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

[サンプル実装](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso68475)

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます

Comment: ちなみに興味があるのですが、どのようにして調べられ、このような対応方法まで至ったのでしょうか？

Comment: これまで自作validationに追加的な情報を付与したい場合に`HibernateConstraintValidatorContext`(`ConstraintValidatorContext`を継承している)を利用したことが有ったので、今回ももしかするとこれで実現可能かと思いリファレンスを読み直しました。`ConstraintValidatorContext`の存在に気づかなかったとした場合でも、["bean validation multiple messages"でググる](https://www.google.com/search?q=bean+validation+multiple+messages)と [これ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26805669/4506703)とか[これ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52038039/4506703)がヒットするのでたどり着けるかなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: ちなみにですが、エラーメッセージ内の一部を動的に変える方法はありますでしょうか？

errors.propertiesに
NOT_EXIST_END_TAG.msg={invalidHTMLtag} should be set with end tag.

と設定していますが、この{invalidHTMLtag} の値を設定したいです。

Comment: 他のConstraintValidatorContextを使っていないところでは

.metadata("invalidHtmlTag", errorContent.get(0).getMetadata().get("ERR_TAG"))
としてErrorContentに設定し、それをContextに追加して表示していました

Comment: 追加の質問は(既に解決済みの関連する質問があると明示した上で)新しく質問を作成するのが良いと思います。コメントに書いても他の人に気づかれにくいという問題もあります。参考: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345/2808

Comment: そうですよね。通知のタイミングがまだ把握できていなくて^^;質問も一応作っていました。この流れからの方が理解してもらえやすいかと思い、コメントに追記してしまいましたが次回からは質問のみにします